# errorCode : "Empty value in restriction scope" in Orion query

Tags: fiware-orion

I have done the following query:

```
    (curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "entities": [
  {
    "type": "Usuario",
    "isPattern": "true",
    "id": ".*"
  }
  ],
  "restriction": {
    "scopes": [
    {
      "type" : "FIWARE_Location",
      "value" : {
        "circle": {
          "centerLatitude": "40.418889",
          "centerLongitude": "-3.691944",
          "radius": "14000"
        }
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
EOF
```

and Orion has given me the erroCode: "Empty value in restriction scope"

I have at least one entity which satisfy the requirements.

I think everything is ok and I dont know where the problem is,so,can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just performed the same query with what's in the 'develop' branch right now and I had no problem. I get a '404 - No context element found', which is normal as my database has no elements of this type/id/geolocation.

This brings me to the question, what version of the broker are you working against?
You can ask the broker via REST:
% curl localhost:1026/version

It seems that you are working against a pretty old broker that doesn't support geolocation values for scopes, but let's find out ...

Comment: my current version is 0.10.1, and I need 0.11.0, right?                   How can I update it?

Comment: with "yum install contextBroker"?

Comment: Actually, the latest release is **0.12.0** and an RPM is available for download in the [FIWARE Catalogue](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/configuration-manager-orion-context-broker).

Comment: I have installed the new version, but when I introduce a XML or JSON code, with an updateContext or a queryContext, it gives me the follo wing :    curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
-:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
Whats hapenning?

Comment: Something seems really wrong, indeed. All details will be necessary to find out what's happening.

Comment: @user3656428, what output do you get when you run a 'curl localhost:1026/version' command (supposing that Context Broker runs in localhost, of course)?

Comment: before the 0.12.0 udpate, it gave me the current version in xml format, after udpating it to 0.12.0 it gives me: "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host". The same udpatecontext and queryContext operations that I did in version 0.10.1, now give me this message.

Comment: The problem described in the above comments is not related with the original topic of this question. Thus, a new question has been posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863875/orion-curl-7-couldnt-connect-to-host