# Orion: "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host"

Tags: fiware-orion

I have installed the last version of Orion, 0.12.0, and when I send a queryContext or updateContext, the system gives me: "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host",

what's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact command that you are running in curl? And where did you install orion?

Comment: for example: "curl localhost:1026/version", it should return the current version but it returns the message "curl(7)..."

Comment: I launched a virtual machine with it, and maybe i have find the problem^^, i think that i launched the orion-psb-image-R2.3 image, but i am now in FI-Lab and it seems that its not available, only orion-psb-image-R3.3 image is available, could it be the problem? should I have to launch a new VM?

Comment: @JesúsZGZ, I don't think so (as orion-psb-R2.3 + "yum install Context Broker" gets the same Orion version that the one instaled in -R3.3., i.e. the 0.12.0). However, you could try -R3.3 if you want, in order to see if the problem gets solved. If not solved, please tell us the output of "sudo netstat -ntlpd | grep contextBroker", please.

Comment: I prefer not to install the R3.3 image, so i have introduced "sudo netstat -ntlpd | grep contextBroker", and there is no output, however, if i introduce "sudo netstat -ntlpd" the output shows all ports listening, and the port 1026 of contextBroker is not there.

Comment: @JesúsZGZ could you verify that the Context Broker process is actually running? E.g. "ps ax | grep contextBroker"

Comment: It has given me this output: "30037 pts/0 S+  0:00 grep contextBroker" , so it is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the user feedback in the question comments, the problem seems to be that Orion Context Broker is not running.

In order to start Orion Context Broker (see reference documentation in https://wiki.fi-ware.org/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Running_Orion_Context_Broker for more detail) you can either:

- Use the `/etc/init.d/contextBroker start` command (run it as root or with sudo privileges)
- Using `contextBroker` command directly

  - In order to check that everything is ok, it uses to be a good idea to do a first run in foreground with maximum tracelevel activated, i.e. `contextBroker -fg -t 0-255`. Once you ensure that it works properly (e.g. curl version, etc.), then interrupt the process with Ctrl+C in the console and run it in background.

Comment: yes, it was my problem, for some reason, contextBroker was not running, now its solved and running. Thanks for your support!